Stacked bar chart from dataframe
Program
Here's a small Python program that gets tax data via the treasury.gov API:
import pandas as pd
import treasury_gov_pandas
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
df = treasury_gov_pandas.update_records(
    url = 'https://api.fiscaldata.treasury.gov/services/api/fiscal_service/v1/accounting/dts/deposits_withdrawals_operating_cash')

df['record_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['record_date'])

df['transaction_today_amt'] = pd.to_numeric(df['transaction_today_amt'])

tmp = df[(df['transaction_type'] == 'Deposits') &   ((df['transaction_catg'].str.contains('Tax'))   |   (df['transaction_catg'].str.contains('FTD')))   ]

The program is using the following library to download the data:
https://github.com/dharmatech/treasury-gov-pandas.py
Dataframe
Here's what the resulting data looks like:
>>> tmp.tail(20).drop(columns=['table_nbr', 'table_nm', 'src_line_nbr', 'record_fiscal_year', 'record_fiscal_quarter', 'record_calendar_year', 'record_calendar_quarter', 'record_calendar_month', 'record_calendar_day', 'transaction_mtd_amt', 'transaction_fytd_amt', 'transaction_catg_desc', 'account_type', 'transaction_type'])

       record_date                          transaction_catg  transaction_today_amt
371266  2024-04-03    DHS - Customs and Certain Excise Taxes                     84
371288  2024-04-03                  Taxes - Corporate Income                    237
371289  2024-04-03                   Taxes - Estate and Gift                     66
371290  2024-04-03       Taxes - Federal Unemployment (FUTA)                     10
371291  2024-04-03  Taxes - IRS Collected Estate, Gift, misc                     23
371292  2024-04-03              Taxes - Miscellaneous Excise                     41
371293  2024-04-03  Taxes - Non Withheld Ind/SECA Electronic                   1786
371294  2024-04-03       Taxes - Non Withheld Ind/SECA Other                   2315
371295  2024-04-03               Taxes - Railroad Retirement                      3
371296  2024-04-03          Taxes - Withheld Individual/FICA                  12499
371447  2024-04-04    DHS - Customs and Certain Excise Taxes                     82
371469  2024-04-04                  Taxes - Corporate Income                    288
371470  2024-04-04                   Taxes - Estate and Gift                     59
371471  2024-04-04       Taxes - Federal Unemployment (FUTA)                      8
371472  2024-04-04  Taxes - IRS Collected Estate, Gift, misc                    127
371473  2024-04-04              Taxes - Miscellaneous Excise                     17
371474  2024-04-04  Taxes - Non Withheld Ind/SECA Electronic                   1905
371475  2024-04-04       Taxes - Non Withheld Ind/SECA Other                   1092
371476  2024-04-04               Taxes - Railroad Retirement                      1
371477  2024-04-04          Taxes - Withheld Individual/FICA                   2871

The dataframe has data that goes back to 2005:
>>> tmp.drop(columns=['table_nbr', 'table_nm', 'src_line_nbr', 'record_fiscal_year', 'record_fiscal_quarter', 'record_calendar_year', 'record_calendar_quarter', 'record_calendar_month', 'record_calendar_day', 'transaction_mtd_amt', 'transaction_fytd_amt', 'transaction_catg_desc', 'account_type', 'transaction_type'])

       record_date                                   transaction_catg  transaction_today_amt
2       2005-10-03                   Customs and Certain Excise Taxes                    127
7       2005-10-03                              Estate and Gift Taxes                     74
10      2005-10-03                          FTD's Received (Table IV)                   2515
12      2005-10-03  Individual Income and Employment Taxes, Not Wi...                    353
21      2005-10-03                          FTD's Received (Table IV)                  15708
...            ...                                                ...                    ...
371473  2024-04-04                       Taxes - Miscellaneous Excise                     17
371474  2024-04-04           Taxes - Non Withheld Ind/SECA Electronic                   1905
371475  2024-04-04                Taxes - Non Withheld Ind/SECA Other                   1092
371476  2024-04-04                        Taxes - Railroad Retirement                      1
371477  2024-04-04                   Taxes - Withheld Individual/FICA                   2871

Question
I'd like to plot this data as a stacked bar chart.

x-axis should be 'record_date'.
y-axis should be the 'transaction_today_amt'.
The 'transaction_catg' values should be used for the stacked items.

I'm open to any plotting library. I.e. matplotlib, bokeh, plotly, etc.
What's a good way to implement this?

I have create dummy df and tested it worked
This code creates a DataFrame with random transaction data grouped by date and category. It then pivots the data to display a stacked bar chart where each bar represents a date, and the stack segments represent transaction amounts for different categories. I hope that solution help your project.
And final code is shown below.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DayLocator

data = {
    'record_date': pd.to_datetime(['2023-10-01', '2023-10-02', '2023-10-03','2023-10-04', '2023-10-05', '2023-10-06','2023-10-07', '2023-10-08', '2023-10-09'] * 5),
    'transaction_catg': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] * 9,
    'transaction_today_amt': np.random.randint(100, 1000, 45)
}
tmp = pd.DataFrame(data)

tmp_agg = tmp.groupby(['record_date', 'transaction_catg'])['transaction_today_amt'].sum().reset_index()

tmp_agg['record_date'] = tmp_agg['record_date'].dt.date

pivot_df = tmp_agg.pivot(index='record_date', columns='transaction_catg', values='transaction_today_amt').fillna(0)

ax = pivot_df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(10, 6))

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(DayLocator(interval=3))

plt.xticks(rotation=45)

plt.xlabel('Record Date')
plt.ylabel('Transaction Today Amount')
plt.title('Stacked Bar Chart of Transaction Amounts by Category and Date')

plt.show()

Output is like :


Muhammed, thank you for your suggestion. It does appear to work! However, two issues. If you try it on the actual data, it takes a very long time. To get it to run, I used only the last 1000 records. Also, the x-axis is not legible. See this screenshot:   https://i.imgur.com/thMHIOG.png

mdates locators can help to solve the x-axis problem. About time not sure how can I improve that. @dharmatech

@dharmatech I have edited with adding a locator. You'll need to choose locator depends on your code. For your code u can use MonthLocator or YearLocator it will help you to solve x-axis problem.

Yup, the x-axis looks better. If I zoom in here's what it looks like: https://i.imgur.com/SsV5xWJ.png

I was able to load the entire dataset. The only drawback, as I mention, is that the performance of the matplotlib UI is very slow with a dataset this large. I may look into converting this to bokeh or plotly for this case.

I posted an answer based on your suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78287908/268581

The other issue is that colors are being reused for other categories. For example, blue is used for two different categories.

@dharmatech u can use colormap example ax = pivot_df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(10, 6),colormap="tab20")  u can find more option in https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html

I converted the code to bokeh. It's quite fast now! Code is available here. I also gave you credit in the README.  https://github.com/dharmatech/tga_taxes.py/tree/main

@dharmatech I apprecited

Here's a complete program based on Muhammed's answer:
import pandas as pd
import treasury_gov_pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
df = treasury_gov_pandas.update_records(
    url = 'https://api.fiscaldata.treasury.gov/services/api/fiscal_service/v1/accounting/dts/deposits_withdrawals_operating_cash')

df['record_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['record_date'])

df['transaction_today_amt'] = pd.to_numeric(df['transaction_today_amt'])

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

tmp = df[(df['transaction_type'] == 'Deposits') &   ((df['transaction_catg'].str.contains('Tax'))   |   (df['transaction_catg'].str.contains('FTD')))   ]

# tmp.drop(columns=['table_nbr', 'table_nm', 'src_line_nbr', 'record_fiscal_year', 'record_fiscal_quarter', 'record_calendar_year', 'record_calendar_quarter', 'record_calendar_month', 'record_calendar_day', 'transaction_mtd_amt', 'transaction_fytd_amt', 'transaction_catg_desc', 'account_type', 'transaction_type'])

# tmp.tail(20).drop(columns=['table_nbr', 'table_nm', 'src_line_nbr', 'record_fiscal_year', 'record_fiscal_quarter', 'record_calendar_year', 'record_calendar_quarter', 'record_calendar_month', 'record_calendar_day', 'transaction_mtd_amt', 'transaction_fytd_amt', 'transaction_catg_desc', 'account_type', 'transaction_type'])

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

tmp_agg = tmp.groupby(['record_date', 'transaction_catg'])['transaction_today_amt'].sum().reset_index()

tmp_agg['record_date'] = tmp_agg['record_date'].dt.date

pivot_df = tmp_agg.pivot(index='record_date', columns='transaction_catg', values='transaction_today_amt').fillna(0)

# ax = pivot_df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)

# ax = pivot_df.tail(1000).plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)

ax = pivot_df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.DayLocator(interval=10))

plt.xticks(rotation=45)

plt.ylabel('transaction_today_amt')

plt.title('TGA Taxes')

plt.ion()

plt.show()

Screenshot

If I zoom in, it looks as follows:

Drawbacks
The drawbacks to matplotlib is that the UI is very slow with a dataset this large.

You can use pandas, it comes with integrated matplotlib functions such as the plot() method, and you can specify that you want a stacked bar chart as follow (you first need to pivot your dataframe):
# First agg the data
df_agg = df.groupby(['record_date', 'transaction_catg']).agg({'transaction_today_amt': 'sum'}).reset_index()

# Pivot the dataframe
pivot_df = df_agg.pivot(index='record_date', columns='transaction_catg', values='transaction_today_amt')

# Plot stacked bar chart
pivot_df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(10, 6))
plt.title('Stacked Bar Chart of Transaction Amount by Category')
plt.xlabel('Record Date')
plt.ylabel('Transaction Amount')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.legend(title='Transaction Category', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left') # Put legend outside of the plot
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


With the following line: pivot_df = tmp.pivot(index='record_date', columns='transaction_catg', values='transaction_today_amt') I get: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape.

Hum, you aggregate the data before pivoting it. Using a groupby for example, I will edit the post.
